# Springboot with Spark in Yarn mode

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to run living spark session using spring boot. My aim is to run spark in Yarn mode with springboot.

1. I would like to have only only one jar file as artifact and do not want to separate spark dependencies
2. Apart from below code do I need to add any configuration? When I am trying it always try to connect to localhost instead of actual host.
   (RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
   20/01/23 20:14:14 INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032)
3. Is there any separate configuration is required to log worker logs along with driver logs?

> ```
> SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().
>  set("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "Dlog4j.configuration=file://src/main/resources/log4j.properties").
>  set("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions","Dlog4j.configuration=file://src/main/resources/log4j.properties").
>  set("yarn.resoursemanager.address","http://my-yarn-host").
>  set("spark.yarn.jars","BOOT-INF/lib/spark-*.jar").
>  setAppName("NG-Workbench").setMaster("yarn");
>
> JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
> List<String> word = new ArrayList<>();
> word.add("Sidd");
> JavaRDD<String> words = sc.parallelize(Arrays.asList("Michel", "Steve"));
> Map<String, Long> wordCounts = words.countByValue();
> wordCounts.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " " + v));
> sc.close();
> ```

Comment: Is your problem resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you to add some configuations files to your artifact:

- yarn-site.xml
- core-site.xml
- hdfs-site.xml
- mapred-site.xml

otherwise you can add these 2 properties in your spark-conf :

- spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.address : "XXXX:8050"
- spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.hostname: "XXXX"